# How to download the English version of Safari

Tags: download, safari

I always get the Russian version of Safari, I'm not really sure for what reason, but I want the English version for Windows. **How to get it?**

Comment: Are you running Windows or Mac OS X? What is your language preference set to in the OS?

Comment: i am running windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a Windows version (XP/Vista/7) I have pulled the latest version from Apple's site and put it here:

http://www.jacksonstage.com/SafariSetup.exe
(File since removed from the server)

I am confident this will be the english version.

Matthew Rankin makes good points above... the problem may be a localization issue with your OS.

Answer (score 1):

The official download location is [here](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#internet).

Another download is available from [filehippo](http://filehippo.com/download_safari/).

Comment: "The official download location is here." I couldn't find the link to download. Could you verify this?

Comment: @MichelAyres: This has changed since 2009. I updated the Apple link above, the filehippo one is still ok.